# Error with url rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/projet/([0-9\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /index.php?p=projet&idapp=$1&app=$2 [L]
```

But with that: "projet/1/storage", I get an error 404.
I would like to have an URL like this, and I don't find my error.

Comment: remove the leading `/` before projet: `RewriteRule ^projet/...`

Comment: Thank you so much Dusan Bajic !! You are the best !!

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by [Dusan Bajic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145196/dusan-bajic) (from comment)*

Remove the leading `/` before projet: `RewriteRule ^projet/...`

```
RewriteRule ^projet/([0-9\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /index.php?p=projet&idapp=$1&app=$2 [L]
```